# Expand tablix upwards when height increases

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have a subreport that contains a small tablix at the bottom of the page. There is nothing above it, and it is inside of a rectangle that stretches to the top of the page.

As I add data, the tablix grows vertically downward, making two pages, but not using the whitespace above it.

How can I have the tablix always near the bottom of the page, and if it hits the bottom of the report, to start growing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

Report items such as tablixes have two relevant properties:

- Height;
- Top (e.g. Position).

Only the first one can be dynamic. The latter can't be part of an expression. There also is not an option to set a fixed bottom (like you could do in CSS).